# Exception when running .NET 4.0 application from network share

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, socketexception

I have a .NET 4.0 C# console application.  The application is deployed to a network file share (which I believe is a Windows 2000 Server file server) like this:

```
\\server\share\Apps\Beta\Group\JobName\JobName.exe
```

The agent machine that will execute the application is a Windows 2008 R2 Server, x64. I use a domain user account to run the application from the command line. When run under a certain account we'll call *UserBeta*, the application throws the following exception when trying to connect to a WCF service:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied
```

The user account, *UserBeta*, has Modify, Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read and Write permissions introduced at the folder **Beta** and inherited by the child folders in the above path.  If I use a second user account, *UserStage*, which has the same permissions except that they are introduced one folder higher, at the **Apps** folder, the application runs without exception. Both accounts belong to the local Administrators group on the agent server.

Interestingly enough, if the application is executed as *UserBeta* within 15 seconds or so of it being executed as *UserStage*, it will also run successfully.

I should also note that the application runs fine if run from a local drive as the *GroupBeta* account, so there seems to be some sort of trust issue with the particular account running from the network share.

I need the application to run as the *UserBeta* account from the network share. ClickOnce is currently not an option. I believe I could solve the problem by adding the permissions for *UserBeta* at the **Apps** folder, however I don't like throwing more access at something unless that's really the issue.  If anyone has any other ideas or can point me to the reason adjusting permissions is the correct course of action, I'd be much appreciative.

Comment: Could it be related to [this patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580188)? The error message is different, but it seems to affect the same code path.

Comment: When first deployed, I was seeing that exact SecurityException.  I did apply the hotfix and the SecurityException ceased, but this current SocketException was uncovered.