# How can I get an application running from a shared folder to connect to localhost?

Tags: c#, http, shared-directory

My application needs to send a POST request to localhost. It works when I run it from my hard drive, but when I run it from a shared drive I get this:

************** Exception Text **************

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied

The relevant part of the code is here:

```
private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/RESTWS/v1/call");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "request={\"target\":\"bridge\",\"operation\":\"makeCall\",\"params\":[\"" + Number + "\",3000000000000000012,true,0,null]}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();       
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

I'm not sure I understand what's happening correctly. Is it that localhost is interpreted as the file server's address? Is it some kind of security/permissions issue? (I have full access to the shared folder, but I don't have any access to the file server).

And less importantly, how can I make it work? Changing localhost to the actual hostname doesn't work because the request gets rejected -- the firewall seems to be blocking the requests in that case.

[The question linked in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168880) is similar but I already know that it works off the hard drive and doesn't work off the shared drive. The asker of that question seems to have been satisfied with being told that in the accepted answer. I'm not. [The answer from Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669361/1188637) seems to offer a solution but unfortunately I didn't do anything in my case. My app.config file looks like this currently and nothing changed after I recompiled the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

I haven't used the app.config file before and I just realized that I need to put the app.config file in the same share folder as the .exe file. Now I'm getting this:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Unable to connect to the remote server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168880/error-creating-the-web-proxy-specified-in-the-system-net-defaultproxy-configur)

Comment: @Gusman I've edited to show that those answers are not satisfactory to me.

Comment: I think it's more similar to this one actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194823/exception-when-running-net-4-0-application-from-network-share

Sadly, neither one of these questions have an answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am responding to an old post, but after spending days looking into this issue, I discovered one reason for the rather unhelpful "invalid argument" exception when running a .NET application from a UNC share. Our app's folder was nested a few folders deep, such as:

> \\server\foo1\foo2\ourapp\ourapp.exe

Our users had rights to the ourapp folder via security group membership and could run the app just fine using the above UNC path. But as soon as the app tried to make a webservice call, we'd get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating the
> Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration
> section. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument
> was supplied

It turns out that we also needed to grant read permissions for our group (or you can do this using authenticated users) to the parent folders (foo1 and foo2). Once we did that, the app was able to make the webservice call. I suspect that there's some sort of "feature" in Microsoft's socket code where it tries to search upstream for something (perhaps the default proxy mentioned in the exception?) and not having rights to those parental folders causes it to throw the obscure exception. Once we added those read rights, our app is able to make the webservice calls.